# C# Migrations triggers update

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-migration

I have an existing DB migration created for triggers in a partial class. Now I need to update this triggers. The exit code

```
 string triggerBodyIns = TriggerBodyIns;
 string triggerBodyUpd = TriggerBodyUpd;
 string triggerBodyDel = TriggerBodyDel;

 this.CreateTrigger(SchemaName, tableName, "_INS", TriggerType.Insert, 
 false,triggerBodyIns.Replace("XXXXXX", tableName));

 this.CreateTrigger(SchemaName, tableName, "_UPD", TriggerType.Update, 
 false,triggerBodyUpd.Replace("XXXXXX", tableName));
 this.CreateTrigger(SchemaName, tableName, "_DEL", TriggerType.Delete, false,
 triggerBodyDel.Replace("XXXXXX", tableName));
```

I am trying to write the following SQL statement but I am getting a syntax error. For each of the 3 triggers mentioned above

```
this.Sql($"ALTER TRIGGER {SchemaName},{tableName},_INS,{TriggerType.Insert},{false},{triggerBodyIns.Replace(XXXXXX ,{tableName})}");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it

```
Sql($"ALTER TRIGGER {SchemaName}.[UserAccess__INS] ON {SchemaName}.{tableName} FOR Insert  AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON declare @Now as DateTimeOffset = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET () declare @EntityName as nvarchar = \'{tableName}\' INSERT SynchronisationData (Id, EntityName, EntityKey, UpdateTime, UpdateType, Created, CreatedBy, Modified, ModifiedBy) SELECT NEWID(), \'{tableName}\', Id, Created, 0, @Now,\'InsertTrigger\', @Now,\'InsertTrigger\'FROM inserted END");
Sql($"ALTER TRIGGER {SchemaName}.[UserAccess__UPD] ON {SchemaName}.{tableName} FOR Update  AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON declare @Now as DateTimeOffset = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET () declare @EntityName as nvarchar = \'{tableName}\' INSERT SynchronisationData (Id, EntityName, EntityKey, UpdateTime, UpdateType, Created, CreatedBy, Modified, ModifiedBy) SELECT NEWID(),\'{tableName}\', Id, Modified, 1, @Now,\'UpdateTrigger\', @Now,\'UpdateTrigger\'FROM inserted END");
```